# Text shifts into the header when using `fancyhdr` with `todonotes`

Tags: header-footer, positioning, fancyhdr, todonotes, pdfcomment

I am currently writing a KOMA-article document in Latex (Lyx) and discovered the following issue:

In order to show comments in pdf I tried the pdfcomment package and the todonotes package. Unfortunately when using one of the two packages with fancyhdr, the necessary text offset is being ignored, so that the text is written over the header.

With no comment package there is no problem at all.

Is this issue already known ? Is there any solution ?

Thank you in advance.

Edit:

I just tried to create a minimal example (Latex export from Lyx) as I realized, that even with the fancyhdr package only I see the shift at the first section:

```
%% LyX 2.1.3 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\usepackage{float}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy} 
\fancyhf{} 

\fancyhead[L]{\parbox{9cm}{\flushleft \bfseries Test\\ \scriptsize Test} \\ \vspace*{0.15cm} \mdseries \scriptsize Test} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt} 

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}

\section{Intro}

TEST TEST TEST

\newpage{}

\section{Second}

TEST TEST TEST
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Please add an MWE, an short compilable code showing your problem. With KOMA-Script I sugest better to use `scrlayer-scrpage` than `fancyhdr`. `scrlayer-scrpage` is written by the author of KOMA-Script and fits better to it ...

Comment: _What makes a good MWE_ http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3343/what-makes-a-good-mwe

Answer (score 4):

Here's a KOMA-friendly method using `scrlayer-scrpage`:

```
\documentclass[headheight=55pt,headsepline]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\ihead{%
  \parbox{9cm}{%
    \begin{flushleft}
    \bfseries Test\\
    \scriptsize Test\\\vspace*{0.15cm}
    \mdseries \scriptsize Test
    \end{flushleft}%
  }%
}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\begin{document}

\section{Intro}

TEST TEST TEST

\newpage

\section{Second}

TEST TEST TEST
\end{document}
```

[image: header to fit]

Note that both `fancyhdr` and `scrlayer-scrpage` are excellent illustrations of why it is vital to read console output and/or log files. Both packages provide a warning message if the designated content does not fit into the assigned space. They tell you, for example, what the current height of the header is and what it needs to be. `scrlayer-scrpage` also gives you the syntax required to set the relevant option. (`fancyhdr` can't do this as it can't make assumptions about how you are laying out the page - directly, using `geometry` or using something else, whereas `scrlayer-scrpage` makes the defeasible but reasonable assumption that you are using KOMA or typearea and not overriding it.)

Comment: I just tried it and the scrlayer-scrpage works perfectly !
Thank you very much !

Comment: @Pete you should probably pick an answer, as _the answer_ if your problem was perfectly solved by the helpful answers.

Answer (score 3):

If you check the warning you get with your code you will find one telling you that the `\headheight` is to low.  So you need to set it to a propper value, for example with:

```
\setlength{\headheight}{44pt}
```

Then the overwriting is gone.

Please see the corrected and a little bit more minimized MWE:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}

%\makeatletter % <================================================ Why??
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\fancyhf{} 

\fancyhead[L]{\parbox{9cm}{\flushleft \bfseries Test\\ \scriptsize Test} \\ \vspace*{0.15cm} \mdseries \scriptsize Test} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt} 
\setlength{\headheight}{44pt} % <================================= to avoid warning and overwriting
%\makeatother % <================================================== Why??


\begin{document}

\section{Intro}

TEST TEST TEST

\newpage{}

\section{Second}

TEST TEST TEST
\end{document}
```

with the result:

[image]

But better to do this with only KOMA-Script. See the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings} 
\ihead{\bfseries Test\\ \scriptsize Test \\ \vspace*{0.15cm} \mdseries \scriptsize Test}
\chead{}
\ohead{}
\ifoot{}
\cfoot{\pagemark} % pagenumber
\ofoot{} 
\setlength{\headheight}{37pt}


\begin{document}

\section{Intro}

TEST TEST TEST

\newpage{}

\section{Second}

TEST TEST TEST
\end{document}
```

with the result:

[image]

Comment: I will use the scrlayer-scrpage package.
Thank you for your support, great platform !